# Sending Push via Postman using Firebase Messaging

Tags: curl, firebase, postman, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send a single Push Notification using `Firebase` Cloud Messaging service.

This is a working `cURL` command for the same purposal, on which I'm using as a reference.

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<API_ACCESS_KEY>" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"<YOUR_DEVICE_ID_TOKEN>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Firebase\"} \"priority":\"10"}"
```

What I have done so far..

1 - Set the **Headers** appropriately

[image]

2- At **Body** , I'm using `raw`

```
{
    "to" : "<YOUR_DEVICE_ID_TOKEN>"
    , 

    "notification": {
    "body": "Firebase Cloud Message"
  }

  }
```

When executing, I'm getting back `401 - Unauthorized`.

What's missing to correctly send the push notification?

Comment: {
  "multicast_id": 4790719999662534961,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
} got this error

Comment: This Article will be helpful to you: https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3

Comment: This answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670409/1151916

Comment: You can find in this article, [how to fcm send push notifications with postman via firebase messaging API](https://medium.com/@sachinkhard/send-push-notification-via-firebase-by-postman-3f459ea5d170)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The correct way to set up `Authorization` key at Header is

`key=<API_ACCESS_KEY>`

and not only

`<API_ACCESS_KEY>`

Silly mistake, but since this could be useful for someone for testing Firebase Messaging with Postman I'm leaving the question opened.

Comment: I see, you already have `--header "Authorization: key=<API_ACCESS_KEY>` in curl and wrong header in Postman.

Comment: Is it possible to send notifications to a topic using Postman?

Answer (score 60):

Open Postman, click on `Enter request URL` textbox, enter firebase url

**`https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`**

Than change request type to `POST`. See below screenshot:

[image]

Now to click on Header and add two `params` `Content-Type` and `Authorization`.

```
Content-Type= application/json
Authorization=AIzaSyAEb3NhsfGw1ih5mn8cmrGUAXMp86waQ //FCM SERVER KEY
```

See below screenshot:

[image]

Now click on `Body` than select `Raw` and add value as object like below

```json
{
  "to": "eB5papU2Xdc:APA91bFFvc3dXru1fN5JY8U19oHIpfGhPUx7Ll7v9vJYTsIGZ15mDwB2Wpep3flLK85IUqqs2WqJwjYHSDYX28oJ1wTP0R2TDc2ba_uVjUauDcp3pCNKr_0KlghOnS",
  "notification": {
    "body": "New announcement assigned",
    "OrganizationId": "2",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "subtitle": "Elementary School",
    "title": "hello"
  },
  "data": {
    "priority": "high",
    "sound": "app_sound.wav",
    "content_available": true,
    "bodyText": "New Announcement assigned",
    "organization": "Elementary school"
  }
}
```

Now your Postman would look like this. Click **Send** button at top right.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but currently it shows an error in HTML: "<TITLE>Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.</TITLE>".

Comment: This works if you use a server key or legacy server key from Cloud Messaging settings (starting from "AAAA" or "Alza").

Comment: This sends to the given token only. How can I send it to all users from postman?

Comment: This works like a charm and sends notifications instantly. A thing that should be changed is that Title to title !

Comment: This worked. serverKey I had to copy deprecated/legacy key. Where do I get the updated key?

P.S. Thanks for the detailed answer with copyable samples.

Answer (score 37):

Posting FCM through POSTMAN

Body - to is token id (should be generated through instance token)
 write body in raw binary application/json
[image: body tye]

```
{
   "to": "cpa8cZPjq-w:APA91bF122f1Rnhu9v47bL
   YMajaNTHAIU5SzItDwTy9o2MCIveG0PlK78VPvp3d
   CqjwnUKZ4
   ngi1trSyM3_aXttW62iknFfbPGtjRLhZr6wq-3qFdboz8gzdOGPz**********",

   "notification": {

    "body": "Hello",
    "title": "This is test message."
   }
   }
```

header: should have authorization :server key

Content type : application/json
[image: headerimage]
after posting here the success message:
[image: success message image]

Comment: how to get to token? is there an API?

Comment: Read firebase android developer documentation

Comment: am getting sucess=1 but am not getting a notification on mobile

Comment: Hi phpdroid you need to check complete body, message is passing to your mobile but it is not able to pick the body

Comment: how to send to all users, who installed app, instead of send to topic?

Comment: @phpdroid, see https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793/ and many others.

Comment: @CoolMind it's been 2 years thanks for suggestions tho!

Comment: @DevOma for send to all users, is needed to subscribe theme to 'all' topic. and so send to '/topics/all'

Comment: how we can convert same thing in nodejs using rest api

Answer (score 26):

For the new FCM HTTP v1 API, the method of testing push notifications through Postman has changed and the existing solutions only addressed the legacy method of testing push notifications: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

To test on Postman with FCM HTTP v1 API, you will need to first fetch a short-lived Oauth 2 token. You can generate one as per the information on the Firebase site here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

I generated mine using Python using the code below - remember to pip install the package so that you can import the package into your code successfully:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def _get_access_token():
  """Retrieve a valid access token that can be used to authorize requests.

  :return: Access token.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      'service-account.json', FCM_SCOPE)
  access_token_info = credentials.get_access_token()
  return access_token_info.access_token
```

Once you have the token - you can insert it into your Postman under authorisation:

[image]

**IMPORTANT:**

In my case, I had struggled a bit to get this to work as I was trying to test a scheduled task that was going to send push notification every few minutes to FCM.
I had printed the token to my logs and then taken that token to my Postman for testing, not realising that it already has been used in the scheduled calls to FCM.

In that case, because it has already been used, the token will no longer be valid and my Postman tests were all failing. In this case, you will need to generate fresh tokens for your Postman tests.

Comment: I am getting this response but not the notification to the android app. Any idea?

Comment: @Shridhar I have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score 13):

**POST**

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

**Header**

```
Content-Type : application/json 
Authorization : key=your_server_key
```

**Body**

```
{ 
    "to" : "your_token",
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "text": "Text"
    }
}
```

Comment: This method allows it to send to the specified token. How can we send to all the users?

Comment: "to": "/topics/All",  and subscribe that topic

Answer (score 11):

Look at below screenshot how Authorization key is set

Authorization : **key=**abcdefghijklmnopr2qrst253uv124wxyz_9shg

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Have you check this : [Test FCM Notification with POSTMAN!](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3)

### Send Data Message using HTTP protocol with POSTMAN

- You have to copy Legecy Server Key from Firebase Console > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging

> Note: Firebase has upgraded our server keys to a new version. You may
> continue to use your Legacy server key, but it is recommended that you
> upgrade to the newest version.

- Select POST. Enter request URL as https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
- Add Headers Authorization: `key=<legacy_server_key>` OR `Authorization: key=<server_key>` and `Content-Type: application/json.`
- Now Select **Body > raw > JSON (application/json)** and add following code:

```
    {
         "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
         "collapse_key" : "type_a",
         "notification" : {
             "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
             "title": "Title of Your Notification"
         },
         "data" : {
             "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
             "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
             "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
             "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
         }
    }
```

I have created POSTMAN Collection for you, [Run in Postman directly.](https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/4eb3de7c1d078f5ccd3c)

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks! At least, it shows a more suitable error, than "Invalid (legacy) Server-key...".

Comment: This works if you use a server key or legacy server key from Cloud Messaging settings (starting from "AAAA" or "Alza").

Comment: What's the difference between notification and data object? Why do you use both?

Answer (score 4):

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectID/messages:send
```

**headers**:

```
Authorization:Bearer ya29.c.ElrXBjdxUzOI................o7_Y2shX2Je4tEe0
```

**body**:

```
  {
      "message": {
        "token": "dlqj05MCnNI:APA91bGhCX6NhT.................QDpKhGheHyhhJ6T",
        "android": {
          "notification": {
            "title": "New Content!",
            "body": "A new video has been uploaded.",
            "icon": "your_icon"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: where you got this Bearer token? If I take the server key, FCM throws 401

Comment: This token is generated by the Firebase Admin SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to send FCM throw Postman:

1. URL to send:
   https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid-34543/messages:send
2. Request Type: POST
3. Headers: Content-Type -> application/json &
   Authorization -> Bearer
4. In the body section enter APS payload with
   the right device token.
5. Click send.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670409/1151916

Answer (score 4):

İf you want to send the notification to more than one device, you should use "registration_ids" instead of "to" on the body;

```
 { 
    "registration_ids":[
"somethingTokens7234134143",
"somethingTokens3452343185"
], 

     "notification" : {
     "body" : "New announcement assigned",
     "content_available" : true,
     "priority" : "high",
     "subtitle":"Elementary School",
     "Title":"hello"
     },
     "data" : {
     "priority" : "high",
     "sound":"app_sound.wav",
     "content_available" : true,
     "bodyText" : "New Announcement assigned",
     "organization" :"Elementary school"
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)`  was disabled from the `Firebase console`. Check if that section is `enabled` in your `Firebase console`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the content-type : application/json header

it fails with a misleading error if you don't include the content-type header saying:
Error=MissingRegistration

Answer (score 0):

Here is Postman Curl's request for sending Push notifications -

```
curl --location 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' \
--header 'Authorization: key={Server Key From Firebase}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
"to" : "{Device FCM Token}",
"notification" : {
   "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
   "title": "Postman CURL"
}
}'
```

Copy Server Key From Firebase -

[image]

Comment: Do not use the legacy API. It will be deprecated in June 2024.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

What exactly is Server Key? I used (on a pitcure above) server key, and legacy server key but neither of them work.

[image]

Does anybody have clue what is wrong? For token -> I used FCM token I got from firebase messaging like this:

```
firestoreMessaging.getToken()
```

Comment: I think, you have right header, but maybe a configuration of Firebase project is not done. Have you added an Android or iOS application?

Comment: Also you should check `google-services.json` in your Android application. You need to download it from Firebase console and paste into Android application, then run on device.

Comment: This answer is your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723045/send-push-message-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-what-is-my-server-key.