# Send push notification firebase by postman

Tags: ios, push-notification, postman

I used postman to make a HTTP request for sending push notification to a topic, I used this body information:

```
{
  "to" : "/topics/mahdi",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    "title" : "FCM Message2"
  }
}
```

Of course I put the authorization key in the header and the request succeeded and get:

```
{"message_id":5081280333669625878}
```

But I did not receive the notification on my iOS device, where is the error please?

Comment: what do you mean Tushar Sharma ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Push via Postman using Firebase Messaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834020/sending-push-via-postman-using-firebase-messaging)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have

- Push notifications activated in **Capabilities**
- Background modes 'Background Fetch' and 'Remote notifications' activated in **Capabilities** in order to receive notifications while in background.
- Replace your AppDelegate or modify the methods as https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift said
- In the firebase console, change **Cloud Messaging** settings (Project Settings->Cloud Messaging) and upload your P12 certificates. (Read this post to learn how to make your p12 https://stackoverflow.com/a/28962937/4077559)

Edit: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html, to make it work on background, you also have to set the following in the message:

```
"content-available":"1"
```

Comment: I did every suggestion but still not receive any notification

Comment: Even if you have the application open? Using the Firebase AppDelegate methods, you should be able to see the notifications in the Console Log.

Comment: Finally, i got the notification , but still can not see it when the app in foreground , i see it just in background

Comment: That's because you have to add to the JSON returned in the notification the tag "content-available":"1". Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html