# Tap on Notification Bar not getting Message in an Activity if app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) tutorial to implement Firebase *Push Notification* functionality within my app.

But I found one thing, if app is in `foreground` then only I am **getting (showing) message** in a Toast and TextView.

Other hand, If app is in `background` on tap neither I am **not getting message** to show in a TextView and Toast.

Whereas I would *like to show message* in Toast and TextView in both the situations `(Either App is in Foreground or Background)`.

*NOTE: I am pushing message from Firebase console itself.*

Is it possible ?

*MyFirebaseMessagingService.java*

```
private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // checking for type intent filter
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                    // gcm successfully registered
                    // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                    displayFirebaseRegId();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                    // new push notification is received

                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    txtMessage.setText(message);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: if you want to handle notifications in background and foreground then you may need to have a look to this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase) and to post the notifications to app using postman you may need to see this answer aswell [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834020/sending-push-via-postman-using-firebase-messaging)

Answer (score 1):

FCM has two types of messages, Notification and Data. Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you want to process the messages on your client app.

Below is the sample,

```
 {
  "to": “token ID”,
  "notification": {
     //params
   },
  "data": {
    //params
   }
}
```

Behaviour when the payload with types of messages,

**Notification Messages**

1. Foreground - onMessageReceived fired
2. Background - Notification appears on the System tray and handled by FCM
3. App not running - Notification appears on the System tray and handled by FCM

**Data Messages**

1. Foreground - onMessageReceived
2. Background - onMessageReceived
3. App not running - onMessageReceived

**Both Notification and Data**

1. Foreground - onMessageReceived
2. Background - Notification in the tray and the data payload will be handled via extras of the intent on tap
3. App not running - Notification in the tray and the data payload will be handled via extras of the intent on tap.

Hope it helps!