# Send push message using Firebase Cloud Messaging (What is my Server Key?)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]
What exactly is Server Key? I used (on a pitcure above) server key, and legacy server key but neither of them work.

[image]
Does anybody have clue what is wrong? For token -> I used FCM token I got from firebase messaging like this:

```
firestoreMessaging.getToken()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427709/firebase-messaging-where-to-get-server-key for how to get the key. If you get they key there and it doesn't work, the problem isn't in the key, but somewhere else.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes it seems that is something else, since it looks like I use the right Server KEy. And I put correct sednder_id to my manifest.json file

Comment: Please isolate the problem first. With that, you can share the correct information that is need to reproduce the problem in your question. For example: can you send a message to the device's Instance ID token using the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification)? Given the error message that seems unlikely, which would mean that any of your code related to sending the message probably also isn't relevant, and the problem is more likely to be in how you register the device with FCM.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I don't have Notifications composer in my Firebase project? I can't send notifications from my Firebase console

Comment: I already answered in your topic there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56718229/2914140. I think, you have right header, but maybe a configuration of Firebase project is not done. Have you added an Android or iOS application? Also you should check google-services.json in your Android application. You need to download it from Firebase console and paste into Android application, then run on device.