# API request in post man

Tags: api, authentication, request, postman, token

I have this endpoint:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

and this is Body for this Request:

```
{
   "to":"ecidY6ipLTQ:APA91bEdVPCb5hE_QTI2KC8JN5W7rzk-nIvmWbDK5TMa8PqxQ2_eZ8dA0Ywna8pkltZG2GpcKUZs5n6TUv3X2j_EcwRhqZ_I7YP90ae9ACaeeSdiisCPPOOtr0yJ87voM7_Ws8Ceyxy0",
   "expirationTime":null,
   "keys":{
      "p256dh":"BLVHXS5JMpe4NfrFEKF4h29CkJhDHBkv0YuktLZyOkC-1zu9ZNy6odKLV0HzFGboO7Q_YURFDNif8Gmkgt6nylo",
      "auth":"9sgELmiPIWfskF-kEtVHcA"
   }
}
```

I have also

```
Public Key : BF5zWIcdemV31vfkC7lCRQX5sMGk5OSCCesoE274aekn-QRli4DoPkpNcEqwHFBnViJzhzM3Lbl-rmtKYLzXihk
```

and

```
privateKey: '9wAuwA40itA6P8sGk11OYrN4TCc2Aal6iNte2Q5ziyU'
```

I want execute this Request in post man I dont know where should be Public and private keys

for this Reason I got 401 error Authentication error

I hope your help and thank you so much

Comment: check if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834020/sending-push-via-postman-using-firebase-messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in this way you can hit this using post man

first you have to enter your authorization token in bearer token

[image]

after that post your data in body as a json check below image it will send the notification and it's showing the status as success

[image]

Comment: if it works for you please mark it correct and do upvote.

Comment: but where can I authorization token find?? I have only this public key and private key and I got invaild key when i try

Comment: when you setup your fcm account you will get server key from there you have to put that key in authorization

Comment: i have generate this keys in Terminal and Register Service worker with java script and then browser gave me this endpoint and this token in body without open firebase .

Comment: okay is good now